# why does csv remove the 0's in the begining if the number is too big ? how do you fix this?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

For example if i have a column of numbers (large numbers) like 0036812321991 , it shows something like 3.68e+10

If there is a 0 in the beginning , csv removes it and i need the number as it is , no  modification whatsoever . 
I need to retain the number as is

I tried using pandas and convert it into the string using "astype(str)" but it still removes the 0

Any help would be helpful

Comment: Don't convert it to string, but read it as string. Alternatively use formatted output with fixed-width and leading 0s.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the dtype as `str` before you load. Look at the following

```
%cat foo.csv
item
0036812321991
0036812321991
0036812321991
0036812321991
0036812321991
0036812321991

%python
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.read_csv("foo.csv")
          item
0  36812321991
1  36812321991
2  36812321991
3  36812321991
4  36812321991
5  36812321991
>>> pd.read_csv("foo.csv", dtype=dict(item=str))
            item
0  0036812321991
1  0036812321991
2  0036812321991
3  0036812321991
4  0036812321991
5  0036812321991
>>>   pd.read_csv("foo.csv", dtype=str) # To use str for everything
        item
0  0036812321991
1  0036812321991
2  0036812321991
3  0036812321991
4  0036812321991
5  0036812321991
```

Remember, you cannot do numerical operations with an `str` column. Also, it's not because "it's too big". It's because `00005` and `5` are the same number. Why is this a problem for you?

Answer (score 1):

Read the CSV file like this.

The problem with your code is astype(str) converts the integer with removed leading zeros into string. So, that's why you've found no change.

Use the below line to read the .csv file values as strings.

```
df = read_csv('sample.csv', converters={'ID': str})
```